# Why I can't send a Map in flutter pusher?

Tags: flutter, pusher

I am currently working on a project with [pusher](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pusher/), but I am encoutering a problem with ONLY sending it seems like channel.trigger is not working for me

```
send(int status) async {
try{
  await channel.trigger('${widget.data['id']}', data: '{"name":"Zeus"}').then((value) => print(value));
}catch(e){
  print("XXX $e");
}
}
```

can you help me find the solution for this?

Comment: Are you joining a private or presence channel successfully? The channel prefix should be private- or presence-

Secondly is the event name prefixed with client- 

You can only trigger events from the client if the event name is prefixed as such.

Comment: @ChrisC no its just a presence channel, and yes I am connected successfully

Comment: @ChrisC not working :( connection is good but sending is not

Comment: Do you see the event show in the debug console (available at dashboard.pusher.com)? 
Are you encountering any errors? 

You may benefit from contacting Pusher support for this, at https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @doydoy, no, I accessed debug console but there are no data when I trigger the event connection is good though

Comment: This indicates your event is not making it as far as the Pusher service. 
Have you enabled client events in your app settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this one
I did and experiment on the payload and found out that the problem is the payload,
before I used to send data like this

```
{
  "name":"Test"
}
```

then I tried using

```
{
  "\"name\"" : "\"Test\""
}
```

and it worked I dont know if they updated it or not but it worked for me this way